# Github repository backed up with git clone. Troubles using the backup to create a new repo

Tags: git, github, repository

With git clone (options --quiet and --mirror) I've backed up my GitHub repos. They are all local now as .git folders, with the following objects in any folder:

1. branches/
2. config
3. description
4. HEAD
5. hooks/
6. info/
7. objects/
8. packed-refs
9. refs/

[Following this guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-push-an-existing-project-to-github) I managed to get the above on a new repository. But of course this is not what I want. I'm confused as to where my code exactly is. Am I supposed to do something with the packs in the objects?

What i *really* want is the exact setup of how the repo was when the clone was done put in the new repo. Like taking an image of your server and installing it on another server.

Help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you say what you not want, but you don't really say *what* you want.

Comment: @Vampire, updated my question.

Comment: So what part of the result is unexpected if you push all refs from your backup clone to the GitHub repo?

Comment: The --mirror option you used imply --bare. A bare repository is not for working on but to serve as a sharing point, this is why you have trouble finding your code, it is not meant to be easily accessible on the bare repo. You should do a regular clone (without --mirror) from your bare repositiory or from the original github one.

Comment: Was not thinking of the consequences of --mirror there. I will try that out immediately. This means I am checking out the full repo though doesn't it?

Comment: @Zeretil yes, isn't it what you want ?

Comment: @igwan, well that fixed my problem! I'm still trying to understand what checking out a repository actually does because they're used in production, and I didn't want to mess anything up. Looks like it won't damage anything then!